# Apache2 mod_rewrite with download

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess in my project:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) download.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwr=$1 [QSA]
```

And if i go to http://localhost/project/download/?f=xxxxx give me a not found error.

But if i change to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dl/(.*) download.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwr=$1 [QSA]
```

and i go to http://localhost/project/dl/?f=xxxxx works fine...

I not understand why i can't use the "download" word in rewrite rule.

Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Thanks in advance for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and let me know how it works out.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/?$ download.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwr=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: After your answer i only change the option line to:
Options -Indexes -MultiViews and work well. Thanks